# Joining 2 halves of a wall

Tags: walls, building-regulations, building

I'm building a 24' x 8' garage wall in 2 sections of 12' x 8'.  What is the best (and up to code) way of joining the 2 halves?  Will a bunch of 4' nails suffice or should I drill holes and use bolts & washers?

**Edit**: I meant "code" for Alberta, Canada - though I imagine building code for this sort of thing is similar everywhere.

**Edit 2**:  I will be attaching a header above the wall that joins the 2 halves.  My question was intended to ask how to fasten the studs of the 2 walls together:

```
   1st half     2nd half
+-----------++-----------+
|   |   |   ||   |   |   |
|   |   |   ||   |   |   |
|   |   |   ||   |   |   |
+-----------++-----------+
            ^^
            ||
           here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the walls with a double top and double bottom plates. Span the splice between the sections with as much length of the plates as you can.

In my jurisdiction, wood in contact with cement has to be PT, so I'd use that for the bottom plate.

Get the bottom plate nailed/screwed/bolted down first, raise the wall sections onto it, brace those wall sections temporarily. Then bang your extra top plate into place and nail or screw it to the wall sections. Attach your top plate appropriately to whatever's above it.

ps, watch the height of the wall across its length... garage floors usually slope and ceilings are usually level...

Comment: I was going to have a top plate span the gap, but I hadn't thought about the bottom.  Is it really necessary seeing as how the bottom plate will be bolted to the concrete?  Do you know of the best way to join the studs?

Comment: Even if I didn't have your specific issue, I'd have a double bottom plate. Walls tilt in better if they're shorter than their final space. Getting your bottom plate located + fastened accurately is easier when you don't have a whole wall flopping around. In your case, you'll ensure that you don't have deviation from a straight line where the sections join. And I'm not clear what your last question refers to... joining studs to the plate? If so, nails are standard; screws are fine though expensive.

Comment: I'm going to have 2 walls.  At the 12' mark, I'm going to have 1 stud for each wall, where the walls butt up against each other.  I'm wondering what the best way to fasten the 2 studs to each other.

Comment: Ah, I understand. If you're using a framing nailer, just use that. If you're hand nailing, I'd use a few 3" screws.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the internet you will see many examples of exterior wall framing and the accepted practice is a double top plate and a single sole (bottom) plate. The top plate is used to splice sections together since as you are building there is nothing to nail the tops of the walls to. The sole plate can always be fastened to the sub floor or in your case the garage floor.

Since this is an interior wall there is no need for the double top plate either. You can just nail the single top plate to the trusses or cripples between the trusses depending on if you are parallel or perpendicular to them.

The two sections of wall can then be nailed together with 16d nailed every 8-12". If you are attaching drywall or sheeting make sure to adjust the spacing so the joint of the two walls is 16" on center with the adjacent  studs.

Good luck!

Comment: This will actually be an exterior wall, but the majority of your answer still applies.